# Is there an alternative to Project's SetCustomUI for Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with a bunch of normal VBA macros. This file is constantly being updated and distributed as an Excel Add-In (.xlam). So far, I'm very happy with how this works.

Now I want to add a ribbon tab and buttons which run some of these macros. Originally, I was excited to find [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee767705%28v=office.14%29.aspx), but then dismayed that `SetCustomUI` doesn't seem to exist for Excel (only Project), so I wouldn't be able to simply use that in `Workbook_Open`. Other SO questions confirm this, but don't give an alternative.

My requirements:

- Users must have access to the macro VBA code like they do today (the add-in appears as a project in the VBE).
- Updating and redistributing the add-in must be easy. Today, I send them a file to update.
- I want a ribbon tab with buttons for some of the macros.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you you can just embed your ribbon CustomUI in your XLAM file and that there's a tool to do that somewhere at MS...

Comment: I didn't even try this. I don't know why. Let me give it a shot.

Comment: Almost worked. Updated post with results.

Comment: Doh! I had a typo in the `Sub` and I forgot the `c as IRibbonControl` argument. This works now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just embed your ribbon CustomUI in your XLAM file.  I believe that Microsoft has a tool available to assist with this (though you can make and embed it manually as well).

---

From the OP, here is what they did to accomplish this, using the [Office Custom UI Tool](http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2010/08/10/23248.aspx):

*I've tried what this answer recommends: Use a tool (I used Custom UI Editor Tool) in the original worksheet to add a tab and buttons, then save as Add-In. This works perfectly for what I wanted.*

*Here's the setup:*

```
Module mdlMyActions in MyAddin.xlsm:

 Public Sub HelloWorld(ctl As IRibbonControl)
    MsgBox("Hello, world!")
End Sub
```

*XML inserted into MyAddin.xlsm:*

```
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="false">
    <tabs>
      <tab id="tabMyTab" label="My Tab">
        <group id="grpMyGroup" label="My Group">
          <button id="btnHelloWorld" label="Hello World"
                  imageMso="HappyFace" size="large" onAction="HelloWorld" />
        </group>
      </tab>
    </tabs>
  </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

*Note that this is all before saving as an Add-In. Once saved as add-in and installed into Excel, the add-in works perfectly.*

---

Answer (score 7):

Here is some code that I have been using on AddIn files for a while. I inherited it from someone else, but it has always worked well enough for me.

It should create a new toolbar in the `AddIns` ribbon:

[image: Screenshot of Add-In toolbar]

I think I copied all of the pertinent code. Let me know if you have questions or run in to any problems.

```
Option Explicit
'This module contains functions and subroutines to create Add-in menus

Public Const MenuName As String = "Menu Name"
Public Const APPNAME As String = "&Menu Name"
Private Sub Credit_Inf()

MsgBox "Created by YOUR NAME"

End Sub

Private Sub Auto_Open()

Dim NewMenuItemMacro As String
Dim NewMenuItem As String
Dim XLCommandBar As Integer
Dim NewItem As CommandBarButton
Dim ToolsMenu As CommandBarPopup
Dim NewMenu As CommandBar

NewMenuItemMacro = MenuName
NewMenuItem = APPNAME & "..."
XLCommandBar = 1 'Worksheet Menu Bar


'Delete the current menu if it exists (just in case)
On Error Resume Next
CommandBars(MenuName).Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Set NewMenu = Application.CommandBars.Add(MenuName, msoBarTop)

' .....
NewMenu.Visible = True

' Create a popup control on the bar and set its caption.
Set ToolsMenu = NewMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup)
ToolsMenu.Caption = "Who built this?"
ToolsMenu.BeginGroup = True
    With ToolsMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
      .OnAction = "Credit_Inf"
      .Caption = "Find out who built this"
      .FaceId = 99
      .Style = msoButtonCaption
      .BeginGroup = False
    End With

'##Repeat ToolsMenu.Controls.Add, as necessary



End Sub


Private Sub Auto_Close()

'Delete the current menu if it exists (just in case)
On Error Resume Next
CommandBars(MenuName).Delete
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Private Sub EnableMenuItem(sItem As String, bEnable As Boolean)
On Error GoTo Err_EnableMenuItem

Dim NewItem As CommandBarButton
Dim NewMenu As CommandBar

Set NewMenu = Application.CommandBars(MenuName)

Set NewItem = NewMenu.FindControl(Tag:=sItem, recursive:=True)

NewItem.Enabled = bEnable

Err_EnableMenuItem:
    Resume Next

End Sub
Public Function IsWorkbookOpen() As Boolean

IsWorkbookOpen = True

If Application.Workbooks.count = 0 Then
    IsWorkbookOpen = False
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out as well and let you know how it goes.